# How do I add a data to the database on PHP then have the result appear immediately without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

I am working on a grading system and I want it so that you can add the grade of a student on a text box with a button then after submitting it, the text box and the button will then immediately change to the resulted answer, WITHOUT refreshing the page

Kind of similar to how one adds a value in Excel

I want to be like this:

Before entering grade:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyvrX.png)

After entering grade:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO61U.png)

My current code is this, but this only works because I have to refresh the page

```
<?php
   if($row['grade'] == '0')
     {
      ?>
      <td>                 
        <label for="">Grade</label>
        <input type="text" name="grade" id ="grade" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" name="add_grades" id = "add_grades" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Grade </button>
      </td>
       <?php
       }
       elseif(!$row['grade'] == "0")
        {
          ?>
          <td>
          <?=$row['grade'];?>
          </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach it is impossible. You need to separate your Serverside code from the clientand use Ajax requests for this. The easiest way (but the ugliest) is to move the backend code to insert the grade in a db into a separate php file and call it via ajax. Ajax is a whole topic and I could write the code here, but it will be too large and meaningless. You need to change a lot.

Here are some links you could try to explore about ajax :

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Video Tutorial: https://youtu.be/tNKD0kfel6o